# How to link strlcpy in makefile in c- undefined reference to `strlcpy'

Tags: c, ubuntu, makefile, glibc

I'm new to C programming and Makefiles.

I have a function in my c code which uses strlcpy for copying string.

I'm not allowed to used #include <bsd/string.h> in my code so I have included #include <glib.h> .
But while compiling makefile,

getting  error:
/***usr/bin/ld: reg_maker.o: in function `main': /home/reg_maker.c:66: undefined reference to` strlcpy'
/usr/bin/ld: /home/reg_maker.c:67: undefined reference to `strlcpy'***

Below is the makefile I used :

```
OUT=reg_maker
OBJS=reg_maker.o
CC=gcc
IDIR = -I../../../include -I../../../include/xxxx  -I/usr/include/json-c/ -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include/ -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include 
FLAGS= -c -g -Wall
LFLAGS= -lcrypto -ljson-c -lglib-2.0
all: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -g $(OBJS) -o $(OUT) $(LFLAGS)
    
reg_maker.o:reg_maker.c
    $(CC) $(FLAGS) reg_maker.c $(IDIR)  $(LFLAGS)
clean:
    rm -f $(OBJS) $(OUT) reg_maker.bin`
```

I'm using ubuntu vm version- 20.04 , I have glib-2.0 library.

Could anyone please help me out what changes I have to make in make file to compile it with strlcpy

Thanks in advance

Comment: The Makefile is obscuring the problem.  Figure out how to build without the Makefile first.

Comment: Conventions matter. `LFLAGS` are flags for lex.  `LDFLAGS` are flags for the linker.

Answer (score 2):

Code using the BSD functions `strlcpy` and `strlcat` should be linked with the `libbsd`. If this library is not available on your system, you can add the source code for these functions in your own program:

```
#include <string.h>

size_t strlcpy(char *dst, const char *src, size_t n) {
    char *p = dst;

    if (n != 0) {
        for (; --n != 0; p++, src++) {
            if ((*p = *src) == '\0')
                return p - dst;
        }
        *p = '\0';
    }
    return (p - dst) + strlen(src);
}

size_t strlcat(char *dst, const char *src, size_t n) {
    char *p = dst;

    while (n != 0 && *p != '\0') {
        p++;
        n--;
    }
    if (n != 0) {
        for (; --n != 0; p++, src++) {
            if ((*p = *src) == '\0')
                return p - dst;
        }
        *p = '\0';
    }
    return (p - dst) + strlen(src);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [GLib](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/) wrapper for `strlcpy` is [`g_strlcpy`](https://docs.gtk.org/glib/func.strlcpy.html), described as:

```
gsize g_strlcpy (gchar* dest, const gchar* src, gsize dest_size);
```

> Portability wrapper that calls strlcpy() on systems which have it, and emulates strlcpy() otherwise.

---

To use [`libbsd`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man7/libbsd.7.html) version of [`strlcpy`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man3/strlcpy.3bsd.html) directly, the program should linked with `-lbsd` in overlay mode<sup>1</sup> and include the `<string.h>` header.

<sup>1</sup> The details of overlay mode, from [`libbsd(7)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man7/libbsd.7.html):

> The library can be used in an overlay mode, which is the preferred way, so that the code is portable and requires no modification to the original BSD code.

> This can be done easily with the [pkg-config(3)](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man1/pkg-config.1.html) library named libbsd-overlay.  Or by adding the system-specific include directory with the bsd/ suffix to the list of system include paths. With gcc this could be -isystem ${includedir}/bsd.

> In addition the LIBBSD_OVERLAY pre-processor variable needs to be defined.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. But I'm not allowed to link use libbsd or bsd library flag, -lbsd. Instead was asked to use glib-2.0 library

Comment: @Ellariz I've amended the answer.

Answer (score 0):

after installing libbsd and pkg-config(3), compile with this **`pkg-config --cflags --libs libbsd-overlay`** in order to use the libbsd-overlay. your library headers should remain the same as if you were on a system that uses BSD as default. overlay is cool in terms of portability.

[pkg-config-guide](https://people.freedesktop.org/%7Edbn/pkg-config-guide.html)